# Calibrate TV display against MacMini

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi, television

I have a MacMini with a VGA monitor plugged in to the display-port with an adapter. I've just added a 32" HD Ready (720p) TV as the 2nd monitor via the HDMI output of the MacMini with no adapter, and it looks terrible. I think it's being driven at 1080p by default, it looks really ugly.

More importantly, the screen area extends slightly beyond the actual monitor. I've tried changing the display settings from "Default for display" to "Scaled" and changing the option between 1080p, 1080i, and 720p and while 720p looks a bit better none are great and none give me a properly aligned screen:

[image]

My TV doesn't appear to have an option to calibrate the display size, can I do it through OSX? In the past I've found connecting to a TV's VGA input works better but surely if I have HDMI out on the Mac and HDMI on the TV, this should be possible to work properly?!

Comment: A 720p TV can't display anything at 1080 resolution - it just won't happen.  Now, I am confused - your last sentence says "your TV doesn't have this as an option."  Doesn't have *what*?   Also, have you tried just connecting the TV only (disconnect the VGA monitor).

Comment: A 720p TV can accept a 1080p input though. I've tweaked my question, I hadn't proof-read properly.

Comment: A 720p TV used as a monitor is never going to look good, it's just far to big for the resolution, which is a mere 1280 x 720. You fix the overscan [which many TVs do to hide the less-than-perfect edges of a broadcast picture] using the Underscan slider.